# JS not working under SSL in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have an application riding ruby on rails. It's rails 3.9, Ruby 2.1.1.

If I `config.force_ssl = true` then my js doesn't actually work. Some of the JS I have does and other bits don't. They work fine in development or if I run the site in http (no ssl / config.force_ssl = false).

If you think it would be helpful to copy in the js (jquery in this instance) I can, however, there's a whole bunch and the headline here is "works in dev & http / doesn't under ssl"

Has anyone experienced this before? Any advice? Thanks.

EDIT:
In fact it's easy to share the js with you, The js in question is this  https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. In breif: **make sure all js from external sources which your js relies upon is served via https** / ssl.

Fuller explanation: The js I was using (https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/) depends on Google's map js. The documentation had a link to the google maps code, I copied it, it wasn't https.

In the past (in my experience anyway) Chrome used to come up with a warning

> "some of the assets on this page are insecure"

or something to that effect anyway. And it would give you the strike through on the https symbol in the url part of the browser. This wasn't happening, having suffered from it so much in the past I was simply assuming that all my assets were being delivered via ssl.

Upon closer inspection I see that they were not, I'd simply copy/pasted the link to the google maps js from the github installation notes for the jquery plugin.

The lesson - if some js is mysteriously not working in production but does in development and you're running your site with `force.ssl = true` then check the links any dependencies your js may have for ssl.